# Microsoft Dynamics Online: Assign new form to Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I created a new form, which is based on another form for Account Entity. I want to assign that form to Accounts and leave the original form unmodified. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already created a new form for Account Entity.

You just need to open an Account Record. and switch between forms as shown below:

[image]

Make sure your form has been created under same entity.

Once user loaded a form, that form will become his/her default form and next time record will be opened in same form. To go back to previous form, user have to switch again as shown in picture.

Comment: Somehow I didn't notice that. Thank you